# Angularjs stripping out query string

Tags: angularjs

I have a route defined as

```
application.component('myApp', {
  template: '<ng-outlet></ng-outlet>',
  $routeConfig: [
    {path: '/person', name: 'Person', component: 'person', useAsDefault: true},
  ],
  bindings: {$router: '<'}
});
```

Whenever  go to `localhost3000/person?eye=blue` it redirects to `localhost:3000/person`. How to I get angular to maintain the query string?

Answer (score 0):

Add `preserveQueryParams` in your route config.

Comment: Is there any way to do it once for all routes? @Zakaria

Comment: This doesn't work for ngComponentRouter and angular 1.6